# How to make author only click button

Tags: python, discord.py

**i want to make author only button if someone clicked and if this is not the author of the message, then the bot will send an error.but my code is not working**

```py
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(content="test", components=[Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Default Button", custom_id="button")])
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "button")
    if interaction.user == ctx.author:
     await ctx.send("successful test")
```

Comment: Just use an `else` clause after checking if the interaction's user is the command author. You can send the error message in the else clause.

Comment: I meant my `if interaction.user == ctx.author:` not working too

Comment: Really you should avoid doing comparisons with objects, just use the ID for that, you will have much more predictable behavior and you can do more with it in the future.

Comment: The [wait_for()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) function accepts an event. Among all the [events](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord-api-events) There is none called `on_button_click`. Try using `interaction` instead. Also make sure that you are using the latest version of discord.py

Comment: @Sandy They appear to be using `discord_components`, which has an `on_button_click` event.

Comment: @Unknownuser What happens when you add the author check into the check parameter of `wait_for` instead of outside? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `check` function to this:

```python
check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "button" and i.user == ctx.author
```

This checks if the user associated with the interaction is the author of the message.

Comment: It is working but I want the bot send error message too

Comment: There is no in-built method for this. You can manually implement it.